# Lazy filter + flatMap + concat

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What's the best way to do lazy transformations (without creating intermediate collections) 
When

1. Doing a flatMap with filtering done both before and after the
   flat map
2. Concatenating collections

Usually I use withFilter for such lazy filtering, but it doesn't quite work in the more complicated use cases

**Filter + flatMap**

1) Naive approach

```
 case class Item(size: Int, color: String)
 // Assume an order can have a lot of items
 case class Orders(price:Int, country: String, items: Seq[C])

 val orders: Seq[Orders]
 val ca = orders.filter(_.country = "CA").flatMap(_.items).filter(_.size > 4) 
 val rest = orders.filter(_.country != "CA").flatMap(_.items).filter(_.size > 6) 
 val res = (ca ++ rest).filter(_.color == "red").take(100)
```

2) Single path, but intermediate collections of items are created for each order. And I think flatMap also produces a collection

```
 orders.flatMap {
    case order if order.country = "CA") => order.items.filter(_.size > 4)
    case order                          => order.items
 }.withFilter(_.color == "red").take(100)
```

3) Iterators. But I am not 100% sure how exactly it is going get executed

```
 orders.iterator.flatMap {
    case order if order.country = "CA") => order.items.iterator.filter(_.size > 4)
    case order                          => order.items.iterator
 }.filter(_.color == "red").take(100)
```

4) Stream.

```
 orders.toStream.flatMap {
    case order if order.country = "CA") => order.items.toStream.filter(_.size > 4)
    case order                          => order.items.toStream
 }.filter(_.color == "red").take(100)
```

5) Views: Not sure if an intermediate collection will be created for the items in each order (I think it will), and also in general I am not a fan of views (forgetting "force" can lead to bugs)

```
orders.view.flatMap {
        case order if order.country = "CA") => order.items.filter(_.size > 4)
        case order                          => order.items
     }.filter(_.color == "red").take(100)
```

**Concat**

Similar options, but for

```
val items1 = items.filter(filter1)

val items2 = items.filter(filter2)
val items3 = items.filter(filter3)
val res = (items1 ++ items2 ++ items3).filter(_.color == "Red").take(100)
```

Comment: Probably **Stream** would be the most memory efficient. But the bet would be to benchmark, specially if this is very important for you. Also, you may want to give [**fs2**](https://fs2.io/) a look.

Comment: View is your best choice. Views do not create new collections. You can see from the source code here https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/collection/SeqView.scala each operation on views create a new plain object that includes a function or other necessary info, but no collection is created.

Answer (score 0):

Is the solution just to noramlize the classes? In your example you essentially have a nested sequence and to go from nested to one sequence you would need to flatten at some point.

A solution could be a `List[Tuple2[Order, Item]]` with `item` removed from `Order`.

That way you can do one `collect`.

For eaxmple:

```
object Main {

  case class Item(size: Int, color: String)
  case class Order(price:Int, country: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val orders: Seq[Tuple2[Order, Item]] = Seq(Order(0, "CA") -> Item(5, "red"), Order(0, "GB")-> Item(1, "blue"))

    val filtered: Seq[Item] = orders.collect {
      case (order, item) if order.country == "CA" && item.size > 4 && item.color == "red" => item
    }

    println(orders)
    println(filtered)
  }
}

// Output:
// List((Order(0,CA),Item(5,red)), (Order(0,GB),Item(1,blue)))
// List(Item(5,red))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBPa4MwHIbvfooXD8WAlW1sF0Gh22H0MHbodhIPqcaSkcYuiYNu@Nndz6R/qBfxzaPv42sbrvg09dsv0Ti8canxF0VAw61Ao7i1WDuxT6z8FTnW2qVoetWbHBtnpN6xW/bdtMIkByMbkZ/gQTtzvOLEt6LDnpoSbnY2x8oYfqzCec1yfGrpUJAG6PrhCv38UQI34rv6GA5KPFS@J/VqdU0wHSWh@y5F/LKKGZZlMH@iwIg2ZimuxOtzzM7APT1v1SBiRj9zKe2kcoLeC7W@iHqCSkYTqHmv4HhaIOmDlCSWQXYBzk4LoCi8GBYLT2TzoijxeAn8rh6bdVGUPvYNY@RvtKt2Sociy26ys@@cjtE4Tf8)